# Transforming the metric between coordinate systems

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, linear-algebra

The following is taken from Ta Pei Cheng's Relativity Gravitation and Cosmology [book](https://www.docdroid.net/b6EsXGs/oxford-master-series-in-physics-ta-pei-cheng-relativity-gravitation-and-cosmology-a-basic-introduction-oxford-university-press-2010-pdf), pg. 283.

For a coordinate transformation of $x^a \rightarrow x'^{a}$, the metric tensor transforms as
$$g_{ab}'=g_{cd}\frac{\partial x^c}{\partial x'^a}\frac{\partial x^d}{\partial x'^b}.$$

Denoting $\frac{\partial x^a}{\partial x'^b}$ as the components of a transformation matrix $\textbf{T}$, and the metric tensor as a matrix $\textbf{g}$,
the above transformation can be written  as
$$\textbf{g'}= \textbf{T}^T\textbf{g}\textbf{T},$$
as seen from $g_{ab}'=\frac{\partial x^c}{\partial x'^a}g_{cd}\frac{\partial x^d}{\partial x'^b}=T_{ca}g_{cd}T_{db}= (T_{ac})^Tg_{cd}T_{db}.$

I then read that the transformation can also be written as $$\textbf{g'}= \textbf{T}\textbf{g}\textbf{T}^T.$$
How can this be shown to be true?

Comment: The former is true with your definition of $T$. The latter is wrong.

Comment: In your first equation, the $a$ and $b$ subscripts on the right side should be upper, not lower. You have other index problems as well.

Comment: The difference in these two is a matter of definition of $\boldsymbol{T}$. As pointed out by others, with the way you have defined $\boldsymbol{T}$, the former definition is correct while the later is incorrect. Some authors, however, may define the symbol $\boldsymbol{T}$ to be the transpose of the definition you have taken. In this case the latter would be the correct statement.

Comment: @G.Smith  Thanks. I had corrected them.